# Displaying model data in Django using for loop

Tags: python, html, django

Im attempting to display all the course Names in my Course Model,

```
            {% for course in object_list%}
            <li>{{ course.courseName}} </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ol>
```

Heres a snippet from the HTML page Im trying to display them in.

here's my models.py

```
# Create your models here.


SEMESTER_CHOICES = (
    ("SPR 21", "SPR 21"),
    ("FA 21", "FA 21"),
    ("SPR 22", "SPR 22"),
    ("FA 22", "FA 22"),
    ("SPR 23", "SPR 23"),
    ("FA 23", "FA 23"),
    ("SPR 24 ", "SPR 24"),
    ("FA 24", "FA 24"),
)
PROGRAM_CHOICES = (
    ("Architectural Science","Architectural Science"),
    ("Civil Engineering","Civil Engineering"),
    ("Computer Information Technology","Computer Information Technology"),
    ("Computer Science","Computer Science"),
    ("Construction Management","Construction Management"),
    ("Electrical Engineering","Electrical Engineering"),
    ("Engineering Technology Management","Engineering Technology Management"),
    ("Manufacturing Engineering","Manufacturing Engineering"),
    ("Mechanical_Engineering","Mechanical_Engineering")
)
# declaring a Student Model



class AddCourse(models.Model):

    program = models.CharField(
        max_length = 20,
        choices = PROGRAM_CHOICES,
        default = 'Architecural Science'
        )

    courseName = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    semester = models.CharField(
        max_length = 20,
        choices = SEMESTER_CHOICES,
        default = 'SPR 21'
        )

    preRequisites = models.TextField()


    def __str__ (self):
        return self.courseName
```

and here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import AddCourse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
@login_required

def currentpathway(request):

    return render(request, "SEAS_Course_Planner/home.html")
@login_required
def newpathway(request):
    return render(request, "SEAS_Course_Planner/newpathway.html")
```

Nothing is printing out and I believe the object list is empty, but I've added courses via the admin page, any suggestions. Im new to Django as you can tell hahaha.

Comment: can you post your views too ?

Comment: `{% for course in object_list%}` must be `{% for course in object_list %}` - the empty space before `%` is important, isn't it?

Comment: okay I added the views.py, and also the space - its still not displaying them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to go through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/) from beginning.

Here in your view first you need to return the queryset from your Course model and need to pass the queryset as a context in your template.

```
def currentpathway(request):
    courses_list = AddCourse.objects.all()
    context = {'courses_list':courses_list}
    return render(request, "SEAS_Course_Planner/home.html", context)
```

Now in the template:

```
{% for course in courses_list %}
      <li>{{ course.courseName}} </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Okay, I went ahead and added that to the views, and also to the template, im still not seeing the courses however, any other ideas?

Comment: which is the view that renders your template( ***template where you are trying to show the courses***)? @NightBeezy

Comment: its actually the newpathway not current pathway, but I went ahead and added it there. @arjun

Comment: assuming i'm understanding your question correctly, im attempting to display it on my newpathway.html file @arjun

Comment: "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `AddCourse.objects.all'" @arjun, I received this syntax error when I put it in the console, im not entirely for sure why.